# how do I set up windows 10 network discovery

Tags: windows-10, network-shares

I am setting up network discovery. I picked the folders I want to share in advanced sharing. I have enabled network discovery. I have set the four services mentioned to either automatic or delayed automatic. The computers show up in each other’s file browser. However it seems like security certificates and or my avg security software is preventing me from accessing files. Properties for all “shared files have been set to full control.

Comment: Edit your question to include the ACL for one of the files.  The ACL should indicate that everyone should have read access.  If you are getting an error provide that also.

Answer (score 0):

There are two places where permissions need to be granted:

- In Windows Explorer, file Properties, tab Security
- When creating the network share, Permissions button

Both have to be specified, as only one is not enough.